# Issue with Comments section on Sharepoint Modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, comments

Can any one help with the below issue we are facing with Comments section in Sharepoint online Modern pages.
Comments section not visible after publishing the page.
Before publishing it is showing that Comments section will be visible once page is published. After published, we cannot click on it.

[image]

Comment: Comments are working on other pages in same site or in other sites? Did you disable the page comments from admin center? Check it by referring this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-enable-or-disable-comments-in-modern-sharepoint-site-page). Also you need to enable the comments on individual pages (Which you are doing already).

Comment: 1) Comments are not working on any page in this Site. Yes I am enabling Comments on every page before publishing. After the page is published it is not clickable.
With Sharepoint global admin privilige we executed below commands as well but no luck.

Set-SPOsite -identity OurSharePointSiteUrl -CommentsOnSitePagesDisabled $true

Set-SPOsite -identity OurSharePointSiteUrl -CommentsOnSitePagesDisabled $False
 

2) On other sites Comments are working properly

Answer (score 1):

Check if you disabled comments on site page level.

- Edit the page
- at comments, turn on the comments, click publish

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to SharePoint admin center, check whether the comments settings are enable.

Reference:

https://sharepointmaven.com/2-ways-to-disable-modern-page-comments/

2.It may be caused by SharePoint Online performance issue. Please open sites in another browser, then check whether comments work.

Comment: Checked both options. Comments are enabled for all site pages in admin center.
I tried this on different browser, still the same issue.
Comments section works perfectly in all our other Sharepoint Test sites except the above mentioned site.

Comment: Have you made some custom designs in the mentioned site?